# How do I run a batch script from within a batch script?

Tags: command-line, batch-file, cmd

How do I call another batch script from within a batch script?

I want it to execute in an `if` statement.

Answer (score 271, accepted):

Use `CALL` as in

```
CALL nameOfOtherFile.bat
```

This will block (pause) the execution of the current batch file, and it will wait until the `CALL`ed one completes.

If you don't want it to block, use `START` instead.

Get the nitty-gritty details by using `CALL /?` or `START /?` from the cmd prompt.

Answer (score 28):

You can just invoke the batch script by name, as if you're running on the command line.

So, suppose you have a file `bar.bat` that says `echo This is bar.bat!` and you want to call it from a file `foo.bat`, you can write this in `foo.bat`:

```
if "%1"=="blah" bar
```

Run `foo blah` from the command line, and you'll see:

```
C:\>foo blah

C:\>if "blah" == "blah" bar

C:\>echo This is bar.bat!
This is bar.bat!
```

**But beware**: When you invoke a batch script from another batch script, the original batch script will stop running.  If you want to run the secondary batch script and then return to the previous batch script, you'll have to use the `call` command.  For example:

```
if "%1"=="blah" call bar
echo That's all for foo.bat!
```

If you run `foo blah` on that, you'd see:

```
C:\>foo blah

C:\>if "blah" == "blah" call bar

C:\>echo This is bar.bat!
This is bar.bat!

C:\>echo That's all for foo.bat!
That's all for foo.bat!
```

Answer (score 11):

You should use CALL

```
CALL batch.bat
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use

```
call script.bat
```

or just

```
script.bat
```

Comment: If you directly call another script within your script, in case any command in the called script returns a non-zero value (error), the callee script will stop to execute as well, where using `call`, it will continue its execution even with an error in the called script.

Answer (score 5):

If you wish to open the batch file in another window, use `start`. This way, you can basically run two scripts at the same time. In other words, you don't have to wait for the script you just called to finish.
All examples below work:

```
start batch.bat
start call batch.bat
start cmd /c batch.bat
```

If you want to wait for the script to finish, try `start /w call batch.bat`, but the batch.bat has to end with `exit`.

Comment: Is there a way to pipe all errors from each of these scripts back to the main script's output?

Answer (score 2):

Here is example:

You have a.bat:

```
@echo off
if exist b.bat goto RUNB
goto END
:RUNB
b.bat
:END
```

and b.bat called conditionally from a.bat:

```
@echo off 
echo "This is b.bat"
```

Answer (score 1):

to run both the batch files better use

```
       start Call "batch_file_name.bat"
```

if you just say

```
       start"batch_file_name.bat"
```

sometimes it only opens a "cmd window" with just prompt,and you'll see the code is
not getting executed.

Answer (score -1):

huh, I don't know why, but call didn't do the trick
`call script.bat` didn't return to the original console.
`cmd /k script.bat` did return to the original console.

Comment: Consider editing your question to more formally explain what didn't work and what did, including the non working code and working code

Comment: Naïve comment against the ONLY working solution on the page...what else is to explain besides "didn't return to the original console"....so, cmd/k worked for me, too, after I wasted my time with the other "solutions"