# Running multiple batch files from a single batch file

Tags: batch-file

I have to execute two batch files through a single batch file. One batch file has a command for starting a server application and other is a client application. so the condition is that once the server is up, only then client should try to hit server.

I have tried following thing,

parent.bat has a following content

start server.bat

start client.bat

and found that both applications are running separately but could not achieve the order in which it should be.

Comment: So you want to run the client when the server is done loading? And server.bat calls the server? Lets say server.exe? Or is server.bat the server?

Comment: Yes..exactly...i dont want to schedulize the process...is there any way?

Comment: I want to accept the answers...how to do that...please tell me :(

Comment: Click the tick next to the ones that answered your question :)

Comment: Another question is, if the server.bat is exiting after starting the server or if its running until the server is stopped

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you tried

```
CALL test.bat
```

This stops the execution of the parent script until the child finishes.

And be a bit more consequent in research issues.
My first google search for "Batch await script execution" brought up this:
[how to run a batch script from within a batch script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4798879/how-to-run-a-batch-script-from-within-a-batch-script)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to @HappyHacking solution is to use

```
start /wait server.bat
start client.bat
```

That will wait until the server script has finished before starting the client script.