# Automating batch files and powershell script execution

Tags: powershell, batch-file

The goal is to automate the execution of 3 files:

1. A batch file that runs a selenium webdriver automated test suite.
2. Another batch file that generates a reports for the tests run in step 1.
3. A PowerShell script that attaches the reports and sends an email.

How can I automate the execution of these 3 files so that upon running a command or executing a file, all 3 are executed?

This is how my PowerShell looks like:

```bsh
$Username = "";
$Password = "";
function Send-ToEmail([string]$email, [string]$attachmentpath) {
    $message = New-Object Net.Mail.MailMessage;
    $message.From = "c@c.com";
    $message.To.Add($email);
    $message.Subject = "abc";
    $message.Body = "abc";
    $attachment1 = New-Object Net.Mail.Attachment($attachmentpath);
    $message.Attachments.Add($attachment1);

    $smtp = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient("build3", "25");
    $smtp.EnableSSL = $false;
    $smtp.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($Username, $Password);
    $smtp.Send($message);

    Write-Host $smtp.EnableSSL;
    Write-Host "Mail Sent";
}

Send-ToEmail  -email "a@a.com" -attachmentpath "C:\file1";
Send-ToEmail  -email "b@b.com" -attachmentpath "C:\file1";
```

This is what the first batch file looks like:

```cmd
FOR /F "TOKENS=2 eol=/ DELIMS=/ " %%A IN ('DATE/T') DO SET dd=%%A
FOR /F "TOKENS=2,3 eol=/ DELIMS=/ " %%A IN ('DATE/T') DO SET mm=%%B
FOR /F "TOKENS=2,3,4 eol=/ DELIMS=/ " %%A IN ('DATE/T') DO SET yyyy=%%C
SET todaysdate=%yyyy%%mm%%dd%

start /d "nunitPATH" nunit3-console.exe "seleniumtestsuite dll PATH" --where:cat==SignUp --result="xmlreportPATH"
```

This is what the second batch file looks like:

```cmd
start /d "exeFilePATH" ReportUnit.exe "folderPATH"
```

Comment: You want to just run three commands? Do you mind if another command window opens?

Comment: Your question implies that these scripts are written, so I don't quite know why you have tagged this with selenium-webdriver

Comment: Is there a reason the PowerShell script can't just call the first two batch files in order, then execute its own commnds?

Comment: I do data automation for a living but you haven't really described a single technical requirement for how the automation is supposed to be triggered.  Normally, automation is either event driven or time driven.

Comment: I've made the changes to add more sense to my question. Perhaps your questions could be elaborated.

Comment: Write a batch file that call all three?

Comment: I think you are over thinking this.  You already have the capability to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Simply write a batch script that runs

```
call script1.bat
call script2.bat
D:\path\to\powershell.exe -File script3.ps1
```

If you need async:

```
start script1.bat
start script2.bat
start "" "D:\path\to\powershell.exe" "-File" "script3.ps1"
```

Note the pair of double quotes before powershell.exe path.

Note that this assumes your device has at least powershell v2

However, this question is a duplicate of [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4798879/how-do-i-run-a-batch-script-from-within-a-batch-script)