# Start flask with venv using a .bat file

Tags: python, windows, batch-file, python-venv

I am trying to start a flask application using a .bat file but Iam having a few issues. The cmd seems to get to the line "env\Scripts\activate" then shuts down the cmd window. If I run each line individually in cmd then my application starts fine.

I want to automate it so I don't have input each line to start my application.

I am new to flask in the windows environment and .bat files.

I have tried changing the set lines to $env: but i still get the same problem.

```
cd C:\Users\admin\Documents\Flask
py -m venv env
env\Scripts\activate
set FLASK_APP=TrialPage.py
set FLASK_ENV=development
flask run --host=0.0.0.0
```

I would like my flask app to run automatically after executing the .bat file.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Solved it, venv is creating a batch file which i need to run by using the CALL command as found in this post.

[How do I run a batch script from within a batch script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4798879/how-do-i-run-a-batch-script-from-within-a-batch-script/4798965)

changing my .bat code to the following worked.

```
cd C:\Users\admin\Documents\Flask
py -m venv env
CALL env\Scripts\activate
set FLASK_APP=TrialPage.py
set FLASK_ENV=development
flask run --host=0.0.0.0
```

Comment: In windows 10 it' making a problem when trying to change directory but I found the solution just update that line  'cd /D C:\Users\admin\Documents\Flask' . Here \D for drive change

Comment: Does this open a terminal? If yes, does this terminal remain active until you press control+c like a normal terminal?

Comment: How can I stop the application ?